# Replacing underscores with letters of corresponding word in Hangman game in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I’ve been searching for the answers to a couple of questions about a Hangman game that I’m working on but I can’t seem to come across a solution that works for me. From what I’ve found it looks like maybe I’d have to use a global regular expression so that way it replaces every instance of the matching letter???

Here are the 3 main problems I’m having:

1. I’m not sure how to get the letters to show up in place of where they correspond with the underscores. So for example, if the word is ‘apple’ I have my code pushing out blanks as 
   __ __ __ __ __, then when a user presses the P key, I’d want it to update the word to __ P P __ __, then if they pressed the A key I’d want it to change to A __ P P __ __. Currently I have it set up so if you press any letter that is correct in the word it’ll display the full word, I'm not sure how to go about pushing the corresponding letters into the correct index of the word as they are guessed...
2. It would be nice if the onKeyUp events would only register letters and do nothing when any other character is pressed.
3. I can’t seem to find a way to make sure that you can only guess each letter one time. For example, if the word is ‘apple’ and I press the Z key, the letter Z will show up in my Letters Already Guessed section of my page, but if I press Z again, it will show up a second time. I’d like it so that after the first time you press a key it doesn’t register the duplicate and either does nothing or alerts you that you’ve already used that letter.

Here’s my code below, I know there are some things that I probably could accomplish the same thing with by using fewer lines of code but I’m still learning, basically started with HTML and CSS about 4 weeks ago. And sorry for the long-ish post, I just wanted to make sure I put all the details out there.

```js
 // This is our array of words for the game
        var words = ['grey', 'school', 'warrior', 'thunder', 'real', 'shark', 'butter', 'tomato', 'potato', 'university',
          'popcorn', 'progress', 'elephant', 'phone', 'artist', 'handkerchief', 'chemistry', 'picture', 'camera', 'alternate',
          'sandwich', 'water', 'traitor', 'america', 'basketball', 'personal', 'homerun', 'apple', 'banana', 'monster',
          'lightning', 'microphone', 'door', 'monitor', 'television', 'prisoner', 'detective', 'breaking', 'solution',
          'fantasy', 'ocean', 'president', 'patio', 'titanic', 'candy', 'hamburger', 'currency', 'copper', 'buffalo',
          'cowboy'];

        console
        var currentWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)].toUpperCase();

    // This variable holds the number of guesses left
        var guessesLeft = 6;
        document.getElementById("guesses-left").innerHTML = guessesLeft;

        // This variable will count the number of times we won
        var wins = 0;
        document.getElementById("wins").innerHTML = wins;

        var resetLettersGuessed = ""

        // This is an empty array that we will push our blanks to
        var progressWord = [];

        // This is an array that we will push the letters from the current word to
        // for comparison of whether the player's guess is correct or not
        var mysteryWord = [];

        // This will store our random generated word so we can see the answer in the console 
        // for our reference
        for (i = 0; i < currentWord.length; i++) {}

        console.log(currentWord.toUpperCase());

        // This is the code that will push out blank spaces for the letters of the current 
        // word so the player can see the word and begin to guess letters
        for (var i = 0; i < currentWord.length; i++) {
          progressWord.push("__");
          progressWord.toString()
          document.getElementById("word-guess").innerHTML = progressWord.join(" ");
        }

        console.log(progressWord);

        // This is the code that will push out the letters of the current word
        // to the new variable fo comparison
        for (var i = 0; i < currentWord.length; i++) {
          mysteryWord.push(currentWord.charAt(i));
          mysteryWord.toString(i)
        }

        console.log(mysteryWord)



        // These are the key events used to play and to document the letters already used and/or 
        // letters in the answers
        document.onkeyup = function(onKeyUp) {
          letter = onKeyUp.keyCode;
          lettersGuessed = String.fromCharCode(letter);
          console.log(lettersGuessed);

          // This will alert correct and compare the letter guessed with the current word
          if (lettersGuessed === mysteryWord[0] || lettersGuessed === mysteryWord[1] ||
            lettersGuessed === mysteryWord[2] || lettersGuessed === mysteryWord[3] ||
            lettersGuessed === mysteryWord[4] || lettersGuessed === mysteryWord[5] ||
            lettersGuessed === mysteryWord[6] || lettersGuessed === mysteryWord[7] ||
            lettersGuessed === mysteryWord[8] || lettersGuessed === mysteryWord[9] ||
            lettersGuessed === mysteryWord[10] || lettersGuessed === mysteryWord[11] ||
            lettersGuessed === mysteryWord[12] || lettersGuessed === mysteryWord[13] ||
            lettersGuessed === mysteryWord[14] || lettersGuessed === mysteryWord[15] ||
            lettersGuessed === mysteryWord[16] || lettersGuessed === mysteryWord[17] ||
            lettersGuessed === mysteryWord[18] || lettersGuessed === mysteryWord[19] ||
            lettersGuessed === mysteryWord[20]) {
            // alert("CORRECT!");

            // replace progress Word underscore with letter pressed
            document.getElementById("word-guess").innerHTML = mysteryWord.join(" ");
          } else {
            // alert("WRONG!");
            document.getElementById("letters-guessed").innerHTML += lettersGuessed + " ";

            // subtract a point from guesses left
            guessesLeft--;
            document.getElementById("guesses-left").innerHTML = guessesLeft;
          }

          // This code will tell the user the game is over along with a message about
          // their win streak, then it will reset the game while quickly showing 
          // what the word was
          if (guessesLeft === 0) {
            alert("Game Over! You finished with a streak of " + wins + " wins! The word was " + currentWord);
            location.reload();
            document.getElementById("word-guess").innerHTML = currentWord;
          }

          // this is the code that alerts you when you've won the game, then it will reset 
          // the current word to begin another round
          if (currentWord === progressWord) {
            var phrases = ['Yup! Onto the next one!', 'Leggo!','You like the Air Jordan of Hangman!', 'Dont hurt em!', 'Turn up!',
            'Go and brush ya shoulders off!', 'In the zone!']
            var nextRound = phrases[Math.floor(Math.random() * phrases.length)];
            alert(nextRound);


            // reset guesses left
            guessesLeft = 6;
            document.getElementById("guesses-left").innerHTML = guessesLeft;

            // reset letters guessed
            document.getElementById("letters-guessed").innerHTML = resetLettersGuessed;

            // This code generates a new word to guess and then pushes out the blanks again
            currentWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)].toUpperCase();

            progressWord = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < currentWord.length; i++) {
              progressWord.push("__");
              progressWord.toString()
              document.getElementById("word-guess").innerHTML = progressWord.join(" ");
            }

            mysteryWord = []
            for (var i = 0; i < currentWord.length; i++) {
              mysteryWord.push(currentWord.charAt(i));
              mysteryWord.toString(i)
            }
            console.log(currentWord);
            console.log(progressWord);
            console.log(mysteryWord);

            // Add to the win total
            wins++;
            document.getElementById("wins").innerHTML = wins;
          }
        }
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: ;
}

header {
    margin-bottom: 2.5%;
    border-bottom: 0px solid black;
    background-image: url("../images/hangman-header.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 125px;
    height: 125px;
}

footer {
    background-image: url("../images/hangman-footer.jpg");
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 7%;
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    line-height: 3em;
    border-top: 3px solid lightgray;
}

hr {
    width: 90%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    margin-top: 0%;
}

h1 { 
    margin-top: -2%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 50px;
 }

h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0%, 0%, 0%, 20%;
    font-size: 29px;
    text-align: center;
}

h3 {
    padding: 0%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 0px solid black;
    font-size: 18px;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 15%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    word-break: break-all;
}

li {
    padding: 1%;
    margin-bottom: -3%;
    margin-top: -7.5%;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0px solid black;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #9ca6ba;
    background-color: white;
}

.main-section {
        border: 0px solid black;
        height: 55%;
        margin-bottom: 0%;
        margin-top: -3%;
        padding-left: 5%;
        padding-right: 5%;
}

.top-label {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hangman!</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Modified CSS file -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/hangman-style.css">

<!-- CSS for Google Fonts -->

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Javascript is enabled -->

    </head>

<body>

    <header> </header>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 top-label">
        <br>
            <h1>Press any key to get started!</h1>
                <hr>    

                    <ul>
                        <li>Total Wins: </li>
                        <br>
                        <center><h3><span id="wins"></span></h3></center>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <li># of Guesses Remaining: </li>       
                        <br>
                        <center><h3><span id="guesses-left"></span></h3></center>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <li>Letters Already Guessed: </li>
                        <br>
                        <center><h3><span id="letters-guessed"></span></h3></center>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <li>Current Word: </li>
                        <center>
                        <br>
                        <h3><span id="word-guess"></span></h3></center>
                        </ul>           
        </div>      
        </div>
    </div>

<footer>Copyright 2017</footer>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot going on here but I will just try to help with one part of it which is checking to see if the letter exists in the word and if it does, replace the `_` with the letter.

```
const words = ['John', 'Jacob', 'Jingleheimersmith']

function chooseWord(array) {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)].toUpperCase()
}

function fillInWordWithLetter(letter, word) {
  return word.toLowerCase().split('').map(l =>  {
    if (l === letter) {
      return l.toUpperCase()
    }
    return '_'
  }).join(' ')
}

fillInWordWithLetter('j', chooseWord(words))
```

If you run this in the console you will see how the word is updated with the letter if the letter exists in the word, otherwise it returns the `_`. This should help get you in the right direction and you may have to fiddle around with it to make it do what you need it to. After getting the letter filled into the word you should be able to update the DOM with the new word with the letters inserted.

Here it is in REPL.it: https://repl.it/IVO3/1

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple web page based on your code that does most of what you wanted - see below.

My general comments:

1. When using just ES5 JavaScript remember that variables declarations are "global" in its scope so using several var i in for statement refers to the same i variable!
2. You declared all your code variables on the document scope - this is in general a bad behavior - I did not change it but you should read about making JavaScript modules etc.

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   ```

   body {
               padding: 0;
               background-color:;
           }

   ```
       header {
           margin-bottom: 2.5%;
           border-bottom: 0px solid black;
           background-image: url("../images/hangman-header.jpg");
           background-size: 100% 125px;
           height: 125px;
       }

       footer {
           background-image: url("../images/hangman-footer.jpg");
           bottom: 0;
           left: 0;
           height: 7%;
           width: 100%;
           color: black;
           font-weight: 500;
           text-align: center;
           position: fixed;
           line-height: 3em;
           border-top: 3px solid lightgray;
       }

       hr {
           width: 90%;
           margin-bottom: 3%;
           margin-top: 0%;
       }

       h1 {
           text-align: center;
           font-size: 28px;
           line-height: 50px;
       }

       h2 {
           font-size: 29px;
           text-align: center;
       }

       h3 {
           padding: 0%;
           background-color: #FFFFFF;
           font-size: 18px;
       }

       ul {
           padding: 0;
           margin-bottom: 15%;
           margin-top: 10%;
           word-break: break-all;
       }

       li {
           list-style: none;
           font-size: 20px;
           text-align: center;
           border: 0px solid black;
           font-weight: 600;
           color: #9ca6ba;
           background-color: white;
       }

       .main-section {
           border: 0px solid black;
           height: 55%;
           margin-bottom: 0%;
           padding-left: 5%;
           padding-right: 5%;
       }

       .top-label {
           border: 1px solid black;
       }
   </style>
   ```

   ```
   <header> </header>

   <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 top-label">
               <br>
               <h1>Press any key to get started!</h1>
               <hr>

               <ul>
                   <li>
                       Total Wins:
                       <h3><span id="wins"></span></h3>
                   </li>

                   <li>
                       # of Guesses Remaining:
                       <h3><span id="guesses-left"></span></h3>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       Letters Already Guessed:
                       <h3><span id="letters-guessed"></span></h3>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       Current Word:
                       <br />
                       <h3><span id="word-guess"></span></h3>
                   </li>
               </ul>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>

   <footer>Copyright XYZ 2017</footer>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       // This is our array of words for the game
       var words = ['grey', 'school', 'warrior', 'thunder', 'real', 'shark', 'butter', 'tomato', 'potato', 'university',
         'popcorn', 'progress', 'elephant', 'phone', 'artist', 'handkerchief', 'chemistry', 'picture', 'camera', 'alternate',
         'sandwich', 'water', 'traitor', 'america', 'basketball', 'personal', 'homerun', 'apple', 'banana', 'monster',
         'lightning', 'microphone', 'door', 'monitor', 'television', 'prisoner', 'detective', 'breaking', 'solution',
         'fantasy', 'ocean', 'president', 'patio', 'titanic', 'candy', 'hamburger', 'currency', 'copper', 'buffalo',
         'cowboy'];

       var currentWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)].toUpperCase();

       // This variable holds the number of guesses left
       var guessesLeft = 6;
       document.getElementById("guesses-left").innerHTML = guessesLeft;

       // This variable will count the number of times we won
       var wins = 0;
       document.getElementById("wins").innerHTML = wins;

       var resetLettersGuessed = ""

       // This is an empty array that we will push our blanks to
       var progressWord = [];

       // This is an array that we will push the letters from the current word to
       // for comparison of whether the player's guess is correct or not
       var mysteryWord = [];
       var i;

       console.log("Current word is: " + currentWord);

       // This is the code that will push out blank spaces for the letters of the current
       // word so the player can see the word and begin to guess letters
       for (i = 0; i < currentWord.length; i++) {
           progressWord.push("__");
       }
       document.getElementById("word-guess").innerHTML = progressWord.join(" ");

       // function evaluating the positions of the given letter in the currentWord string
       // return empty array in case of failure
       function letterInWord(letter) {
           // the array that will contain the char positions in the currentWord that has the 
           var positions = new Array();
           for (i = 0 ; i < currentWord.length; i++) {
               if (currentWord[i] === letter)
                   positions.push(i);
           }
           return positions;
       }

       // return number of letters that is still not guessed
       function lettersToGuess() {
           var i ;
           var toGess = 0 ;
           for (i in progressWord) {
               if (progressWord[i] === "__")
                   toGess++;
           }
           return toGess;
       }

       // These are the key events used to play and to document the letters already used and/or
       // letters in the answers
       document.onkeyup = function (event) {
           var letter = event.key;
           var lettersGuessed = letter.toLocaleUpperCase();
           var i;

           console.log("You have typed a letter: ".concat(letter));

           var positions = letterInWord(lettersGuessed);


           // This will alert correct and compare the letter guessed with the current word
           if (positions.length) {
               console.log("User has pressed a letter from word: " + letter);

               for (i = 0 ; i < positions.length; i++) {
                   progressWord[positions[i]] = lettersGuessed;
               }

               // replace progress Word underscore with letter pressed
               document.getElementById("word-guess").innerHTML = progressWord.join(" ");
           } else {
               // alert("WRONG!");
               document.getElementById("letters-guessed").innerHTML += lettersGuessed + " ";

               // subtract a point from guesses left
               guessesLeft--;
               document.getElementById("guesses-left").innerHTML = guessesLeft;
           }

           // This code will tell the user the game is over along with a message about
           // their win streak, then it will reset the game while quickly showing
           // what the word was
           if (guessesLeft === 0) {
               alert("Game Over! You finished with a streak of " + wins + " wins! The word was " + currentWord);
               location.reload();
           }

           // this is the code that alerts you when you've won the game, then it will reset
           // the current word to begin another round
           if (lettersToGuess() == 0) {
               var phrases = ['Yup! Onto the next one!', 'Leggo!', 'You like the Air Jordan of Hangman!', 'Dont hurt em!', 'Turn up!',
               'Go and brush ya shoulders off!', 'In the zone!']
               var nextRound = phrases[Math.floor(Math.random() * phrases.length)];
               alert(nextRound);


               // reset guesses left
               guessesLeft = 6;
               document.getElementById("guesses-left").innerHTML = guessesLeft;

               // reset letters guessed
               document.getElementById("letters-guessed").innerHTML = resetLettersGuessed;

               // This code generates a new word to guess and then pushes out the blanks again
               currentWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)].toUpperCase();

               progressWord = [];
               for (i = 0; i < currentWord.length; i++) {
                   progressWord.push("__");
               }
               document.getElementById("word-guess").innerHTML = progressWord.join(" ");

               // Add to the win total
               wins++;
               document.getElementById("wins").innerHTML = wins;
           }
       }
   </script>
   ```